# Fitting data to a B-spline with p=1 in python

Tags: python, spline

I have defined a step function in Python using the following code. The function takes in an array `a` and `x` values and returns a step function `f`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the step function
def step_function(x, a):
    def rect(x):
        return np.where((x >= 0) & (x < 1), 1, 0)
    
    f = np.sum([a[k-1] * rect(x - k) for k in range(1, len(a) + 1)], axis=0)
    return f

# Set the random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Generate random values for a_k
N = 10
a = np.array([-0.25091976,  0.90142861,  0.46398788,  0.19731697, -0.68796272,
       -0.68801096, -0.88383278,  0.73235229,  0.20223002,  0.41614516])
#a = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=N)

# Define the x-values for plotting
x = np.arange(0, N + 1, 0.01)

# Evaluate the step function at x
y = step_function(x, a)

# Plot the step function
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.title('Step Function Plot')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

It produces the picture

[image]

This is a B-spline of degree p=0 (see e.g. [B-spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline)). I would like to replace the rect function with the B-spline of degree p=1 and so fit the data stored in `a` as done in my code. Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: What exactly is your question?